# One of the at least one - followed by singular or plural noun?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number

Which of the following is correct:

(a) One of the at least one fruit; or
    (b) One of the at least one fruit**s**

Comment: They're both wrong, "One of the at least one..." isn't well formed English. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Are you trying to say that the person must choose at least one type of fruit but can choose more types, however they can only take one of each selected type. For instance someone who chooses oranges, apples and bananas can take an orange, an apple and a banana (3 fruit) but someone who chooses only bananas can take only a banana (1 fruit). This seems very strange.

Answer (score 1):

***One of*** MUST be followed by plural. You cannot say **one of one*, but you can say ***one of (at least) two***  or more.

[Learnex](http://www.learnex.in/using-the-phrase-one-of-something/) explains:

> - ***One of*** is a singular term and generally used to talk about a noun or a pronoun.
> - *The noun or a pronoun used after the phrase “one of” is **always in the plural** form* ( as we are talking of one person/place/thing out of many)
> - The helping verb will always be in the singular form, as the helping verb agrees with “one of” and not with the plural noun in the sentence.

Technically speaking, it is grammatical to interpose *at least* between ***one of*** and the complement of the preposition ***of***, but that does not change the fact that the complement must be plural.

So you can only say

> *One of the at least **two [or more]*** fruits

Note that fruits in the plural ***fruits*** is a particular use in order to [emphasise the different kinds of fruit](https://www.vocabulary.cl/english/fruit.htm).

However, the expression *one of the at least* can be confusing. There may be [rare instances](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20of%20at%20least%2C%20at%20least%20one%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20of%20at%20least%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20least%20one%20of%3B%2Cc0) where would you choose *one of at least a number of items from a category*? It is more common to single out the ***one***:

> ***At least one*** of the fruits

Comment: "You cannot say *one of one" - I'm sure I've seen "Page 1 of 1" in the footer of many a document...

Comment: @AakashM Well, "1 of 1" is different from "one of one". "1 of 1" is a particular use of digits in numbering pages and is only seen in documents as an orientation (rarely as part of a sentence). But the issue of the OP is about counting objects and extracting one out of a group.